# Как сделать, чтобы оси перерисовывались сразу с имеющимися графиками?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, matplotlib

Разрабатываю приложение для построения графиков с помощью matplotlib и Tkinter. Добавила функцию изменения положения осей:

```
ax = f.gca()
ax.cla()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
f.canvas.draw()
```

Если графиков в программе, на момент перерисовки осей координат, нет, то оси меняют положения и далее построение графиков происходит как надо. Но, если в программе до перерисовки осей находятся графики, то оси перерисовываются, а графики, построенные до, не отображаются.

Как можно исправить этот момент, чтобы оси перерисовывались сразу с имеющимися графиками?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
In [27]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()

In [28]: x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

In [29]: y = np.cos(x)

In [30]: plt.plot(x, y)
Out[30]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x28e00cd2cf8>]

In [31]: ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    ...: ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ...: ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ...: ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS вызов `ax.cla()` удаляет (очищает) все что было нарисовано на `ax`.

Comment: cla я использую для очистки текущего положения осей осей,так как в программе у меня несколько кнопок. При нажатии, например, на одну из них,отвечающую за перемещение осей в центр (как в данном случае),предыдущее положение осей очищается,и добавляется новое.

Comment: В Вашем примере вы не ответили на мой вопрос. Может быть Вы не так меня поняли. Суть в следующем: в окно приложения, в поле ввода, вводится функция(с использованием gui) вида y=f(x), затем пользователь нажимает кнопку "построить" и график функции отображается на канве.

Comment: Так же в приложении присутствует настройка положения осей графика. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку,например, "Переместить оси в центр" и оси смещаются в центр, но график,введенной ранее функции, уже не отображается. В случае, когда сначала изменено положение осей,а затем введена функция, программа работает отлично. Мне необходимо решение этой проблемы:чтобы график функции, после изменения положения осей, оставался на канве.

Comment: @Ольга, `ax.cla()` - очищает оси и, соответственно, всё, что до этого было нарисовано на `ax` - удаляется. Если вам совершенно необходимо вызывать `ax.cla()` то просто перерисуйте после этого все что было нарисовано до этого

Comment: в том то и дело,что у меня никак не получается перерисовать. В случае,если бы я вводила функции в самом коде программы-всё было бы проще,чем с вводом в приложении. Может есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

```py
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```